# Android: meta-data is also present at

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Newcommer at Android development, and got this error. No clue what is wrong.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Change all support library versions to same version.

Comment: Post your gradle files.

Comment: @NovoLucas posted

Comment: Try refreshing the Gradle by reading the dependencies and Clean Build the project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same version of support libraries either use 25.3.1 with all com.android.support dependencies or use 26.0.0-alpha1 for all.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

or either

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your root level gradle file make sure you have added Google's Maven Repo like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

This will hopefully resolve it.

Comment: I had a similar error where adding the Maven Repo worked.